# How many users can I create in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, user-account

I need to know how many users can I create in GeoServer (2.6x)?

Is it infinite or finite?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing, but I'm going to say it's finite. But really, you should ask how many users do I need as a realistic max, and can GeoServer handle that. I reckon that number is pretty high, but maintenance of users might be tricky.

Asking if a software product can handle an infinite number of users is a pretty vague question, really.

Comment: Hi alexgleith and thank you for your answer.
But also can you give me a clear number of users!
Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be many thousands. What you're asking is like saying 'how many users does active directory support' and the answer is, probably, a lot. You might need to tune things. It'll be complex to administrate. And you may be able to accomplish what you're after without creating many users. What exactly are you trying to do?